# HttpClient.PutAsync finish immediately with no response

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

I try to upload a file with PUT method to the http server (Apache Tika) with the following code

```
private static async Task<string> send(string fileName, string url)
{
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));

        var content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        var response = await client.PutAsync(url, content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

In Main the method is called this way:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...

    send(options.FileName, options.Url).
        ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine(task.Result));
}
```

In response the server should return HTTP 200 and text response (parsed pdf file). I've checked this behavior with with Fiddler and it works fine as far as the server is concerned.

Unfortunately the execution finish right after calling PutAsync method.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing this from a console application, which will terminate after your call to `send`. You'll have to use `Wait` or `Result` on it in order for `Main` not to terminate:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sendResult = send(options.FileName, options.Url).Result;
    Console.WriteLine(sendResult);
}
```

Note - **this should be only used inside a console application**. Using `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result` will result in a deadlock in other application types (which are not console) due to synchronization context marshaling.

Comment: This is the solution. Thx! I see that I must do my homework on how the async exactly works on different types of apps